# Need to remove object from list before insert new object?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and I'm doing a task where I'm using a list of objects. I thought if I inserted a new object, with list.insert(index, object) at a position where it already is an object, the prevous object was replaced!?

But it seems that I have to remove it first with list.removeAt(index) before I can insert the new one, otherwise it was just added and the old left in the list. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) inserts a new item at the specified index, making space as needed:

```
list.Insert(1, "foo");

//  Before              After
//
//  list[0] == "a"      list[0] == "a"
//  list[1] == "b"      list[1] == "foo"
//  list[2] == "c"      list[2] == "b"
//                      list[3] == "c"
```

If you want to replace an item at a specified index, you can use the list's [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc):

```
list[1] = "foo";

//  Before              After
//
//  list[0] == "a"      list[0] == "a"
//  list[1] == "b"      list[1] == "foo"
//  list[2] == "c"      list[2] == "c"
```

*See also:* [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: OK, list[1] = "foo"; is better! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is correct.

But if you wanted to replace an item in the list at a specified index, why not just

```
list[index] = newitem;
```